How to change UIAlertAction's image position?
I want to create a popover menu with UIAlertController which includes customize action items, user can define style like font-size , background-color, alignment and Icon Position (Leading / Trailing), how to change icon position, make the icon behind the title ?
enter image description here
I use the following extension to set color and alignment, but don't know how to set font-size and icon position, please help me find a solution.
extension UIAlertAction {
    var titleTextColor: UIColor? {
        get { return self.value(forKey: "titleTextColor") as? UIColor }
        set { self.setValue(newValue, forKey: "titleTextColor") }
    }
    
    var titleAlignment: Int? {
        get { return self.value(forKey: "titleTextAlignment") as? Int }
        set { self.setValue(newValue, forKey: "titleTextAlignment") }
    }
}


It's better to create your own. You can't do much with the default one.

UIAlertAction does not supporting changing the image's position. I would suggest writing your own alert controller instead of using the built-in one.
That said, it is possible to move the images of all alert actions to the right if you override the layout direction, since the images always appear on the leading side.
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action 1", style: .default) { _ in }
action1.setValue(UIImage(...), forKey: "image")
alert.addAction(action1)
// assuming this is in a UIViewController subclass
present(alert, animated: true)
if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
    alert.traitOverrides.layoutDirection = .rightToLeft
} else {
    setOverrideTraitCollection(.init(layoutDirection: .rightToLeft), forChild: alert)
}


hi @Sweeper, the class never inherit UIViewController like below codes,
public class Popover: NSObject, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
....
so there is an error about cannot find setOverrideTraitCollection in scope.
the popover menu display by function controller.present(...), the controller is a page(UIViewController), can i solve the error by run bold controller.setOverrideTraitCollection( .... ?

@WilliamWang Yeah. You should use whatever view controller it is that presents the alert.
